# textView with truncation swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, truncation

I have a text view with a set height on a table view. As the content of my text view is greater than what fits in the set height, the content is truncated.

That is fine, but my issue is that I would like the text view to contain the first few lines of the content and then have the  ... but instead the first few lines are missing and the text view is displaying the last few lines of the content passed in.

I can't find any examples on how to implement this.

I have tried the following but to no avail:

```
descriptionLabel.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the text is not editable, use UILabel instead, which gives you this behavior out of the box.

Otherwise you will have to build your own Text Kit stack and write your own NSLayoutManager to achieve this.

Comment: There is in fact a WWDC video from a couple of years ago that explains what you'll need to do.

Comment: I switched to a label and this is giving me one line of text with ... but i need 4 lines and then a ... Is that possible with a label?

Comment: You have to set the label's number of lines. You want 4, tell it you want 4.

Comment: I'm stuck on a swift related q which isn't getting much traction, if you have any time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480323/updating-rows-label-based-of-web-service-implementation-swift